# Magento 1 - Quotation and CRM Extensions

Tags: magento-1

I'm looking for recommendations for **Magento 1** Quotation extensions.

If you have purchased & experienced such an extension, I'd love to hear about it.

I'm also looking into CRM extensions or extensions that integrate with stand alone CRM packages.

Again, any personal experience sharing would be very beneficial to me.

We currently use Sage for our accounting.

Comment: https://www.cart2quote.com/ is the one i know.

Answer (score 0):

I would check this if you want to know more about different extensions: [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Magento%201%20Quotation%20extensions)